# How to pass an Azure DB connection string to a Java application?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I was working on a java application and tried passing the db string just as we passed to connect to localhost sql db.But failed. Is there any other possible way?

```
public String db_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://neutroserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=NeutroDB;user=lakshangunarathna@neutroserver;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
public String db_Username = "root";
public String db_Password = "";
```

Comment: "It failed" isn't an error description or error message. You pass connection strings the same way you pass any connection string. Did you get an actual error? Where is the code you used? What you typed here isn't code, it's just a couple of variables. The connection string doesn't contain any authentication information either. Where and how do you pass the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java
this topic should address your questions - if not - please give more details